# reverse array (with argc and argv) + how to print it

Tags: c

i am a beginner in c and i would like to switch the element of the argv array depending on the user's input, using another dynamically allocated array, but i have issues when it comes to putting the value (or char) in this array, the error is :assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] and i dont get the problem... and then i would like to print the new tab but i cant because, how do i do it?

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    /*TO BE COMPLETED*/
   int *tab =malloc(argc*sizeof(char));
   int i = 0;
   if (tab == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory!\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("tab = [");
   for (i = argc; i > 1; i--)
    {
        int k = 0;
        tab[k] = argv[i];
        k +=1;
        //printf(" %c," tab[k]);
    }

    printf(" ]");
    free(tab);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: I don't follow what you're trying to do with `argc`, which is an integer that tells you how many strings there are in `argv`. Why are you allocating a block for `argc` characters?

Comment: it is: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         tab[k] = argv[i];

Comment: That's not the full message. It should include at least a filename and a line number (the two most important parts of any error message).

Comment: im trying to allocate a new tab that contains argc elements (the inputs) and returns the inputs but in reverse

Comment: tewt.c: In function 'main':
tewt.c:17:16: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         tab[k] = argv[i]

Comment: (Not related to your principal question, but you should declare `k` outside the loop, otherwise you will always assign to `tab[0]`. And in the loop you try to access `argv[argc]`, which is one beyond the last argument given.)

Comment: Line 17 is `tab[k] = argv[i];`. `tab[k]` is an `int`, `argv[i]` is a `char *`. Those are not the same type. What do you expect that assignment to do?

Comment: i want to copy the inputs of the user (the elements of argv[]) into tab but in reverse and then print it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a few issues and misconceptions to resolve:

1. `tab` should be declared as type `char **` rather than `int *`. `argv` is a two-dimensional array of type `char **`, so `tab` should mirror this. As it stands, you declare `int *` but `malloc` for a pointer to a memory block of `char`, which is the cause of your error.
2. `k`, the index you're using to keep track of where you're at in the `tab` array, is re-declared and reset to `0` on every iteration of the reversal loop and can't make progress. It should be declared at the loop scope, not inside of the loop block.
3. `argv[0]` is the name of the executable, so you are likely interested in adding only `argc - 1` elements from `1 .. argc - 1` to your `tab` array. You can adjust your `malloc` call size accordingly.
4. In your loop, setting `i = argc` is out of the array bounds of `argv`; point it to `i = argc - 1` to access the last element in `argv`.
5. `printf` will need the `%s` format string instead of `%c` to print each element of `argv`/`tab` since elements may be more than one character.

Here's one possible solution (I've moved printing outside of the reversal loop to separate concerns):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i, j;
    char **tab = malloc((argc - 1) * sizeof(*tab));

    if (tab == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 1, j = argc - 2; i < argc; i++, j--) {
        tab[j] = argv[i];
    }

    printf("tab = [");

    for (i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++) {
        printf(" %s,", tab[i]);
    }

    puts(" ]");
    free(tab);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.exe a b c d e f g h
tab = [ h, g, f, e, d, c, b, a, ]
```

Comment: It's nice to help beginners without completely solving the problem so that they can learn something on their own.

Comment: @Caleb This post offers itemized debugging instructions and ample opportunity for learning and growth. Generally, SO answers entail complete, working and accurate solutions with explanation, as this does. I reserve downvotes for incomplete/inaccurate information and posts that add nothing to the discussion, but you're entitled to your own viewpoint.

Comment: thank you i was stuck with another error i didn understand either, i'll try the code and learn from it :)

Comment: and i agree that not solving a problem to make the other think about it is ok but here i was really stuck and it definitely helped me seeing the code and analyzing what was wrong with mine

Comment: No problem. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thank you for the time you took!

Comment: @ggorlen I hope you'll at least consider SO's tradition of [trying to help someone learn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) instead of providing a complete solution to beginner questions. Also: don't make assumptions about downvotes. Also: Since your code doesn't need to modify the strings in `tab`, there's little reason to copy each one; you can copy the pointers instead of doing the whole malloc/memcpy thing for each string.

Comment: @Caleb You're right, and actually adding the copy causes a memory leak without `free`, so I'll remove it; just sketched that up on a whim without ASAN. It's worth noting that the new array is an array of references. As for your link, are you sure this is a homework question? There are a lot of assumptions from both parties, and even if this is homework, I feel that my answer clearly "helps a student learn" and "is in their interest". There are solutions that offer a huge gob of finished code without any explanation, and I don't feel that is the case here. Apologies for the DV assumption.

Answer (score 2):

> assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] tab[k] = argv[I];

You're getting this warning because you've declared `tab` as type `int *`. `argv` is an array of `char *`, so you're assigning a pointer (again, `char *` to an entry in an array of integers.

> im trying to allocate a new tab that contains argc elements (the inputs) and returns the inputs but in reverse

OK, but what you're code is actually doing is:

```
int *tab =malloc(argc*sizeof(char));
```

In English: allocate a block of size `argc * 1` and assign its address to a pointer that's typed as a pointer to integers. It sounds like what you mean to do is to create an array of character pointers, i.e. `malloc(argc * sizeof(char*))`, but if you do that then `tab` should also be typed as `char **`.

Comment: and then i want to print the elements of tab and i am confused on which flags to use in printf

Comment: @MathisFuentes `%s` is the printf format specifier for strings, which I think is what you want. Printf format strings have a lot of options, especially for numeric types, so you should keep [a reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) close at hand.